# Hard wrap hard refill

Tags: shell, awk, sed, wrap

Given this file:

```
$ cat file
alfa bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot golf hotel india juliet kilo lima mike
november oscar papa quebec romeo sierra tango
uniform_victor_whiskey_xray yankee zulu
```

I would like to hard break at 70, but I would also like to hard refill. I tried
"fold", but it did not refill:

```
$ fold -w 70 file
alfa bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot golf hotel india juliet kilo lim
a mike
november oscar papa quebec romeo sierra tango
uniform_victor_whiskey_xray yankee zulu
```

"fmt" will refill, but I could only get it to break on spaces so no guarantee to
wrap on exactly 70:

```
$ fmt file
alfa bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot golf hotel india juliet
kilo lima mike november oscar papa quebec romeo sierra tango
uniform_victor_whiskey_xray yankee zulu
```

I tried "pr" but it seems to just truncate the line without wrapping:

```
$ pr -t -W 70 file
alfa bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot golf hotel india juliet kilo lim
november oscar papa quebec romeo sierra tango
uniform_victor_whiskey_xray yankee zulu
```

Maybe these commands have some option I am missing, or maybe Awk or Sed
solution. I would prefer to avoid heavier solutions (Perl PHP Ruby).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using sed

With GNU sed:

```
$ sed -zE 's/\n/ /g; s/.{70}/&\n/g; s/$/\n/' file
alfa bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot golf hotel india juliet kilo lim
a mike november oscar papa quebec romeo sierra tango uniform_victor_wh
iskey_xray yankee zulu
```

With any POSIX sed:

```
sed -zE 'H;1h;$!d;x; s/\n/ /g; s/.{70}/&\n/g; s/$/\n/' file
```

#### Using awk

```
$ awk  '{r=(length(r)?r" "$0:$0); while(length(r)>70){print substr(r,1,70); r=substr(r,71)}} END{print r}' file
alfa bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot golf hotel india juliet kilo lim
a mike november oscar papa quebec romeo sierra tango uniform_victor_wh
iskey_xray yankee zulu
```

#### With tr and fold

```
$ tr '\n' ' ' <file | fold -w 70
alfa bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot golf hotel india juliet kilo lim
a mike november oscar papa quebec romeo sierra tango uniform_victor_wh
iskey_xray yankee zulu
```

The above does not produce a trailing newline but we can add one if needed with `echo ""`:

```
tr '\n' ' ' <file | fold -w 70; echo
```

Answer (score 1):

This wont work in all cases, but it should cover most use cases:

```
$ fmt -w 2500 file | fold -w 70
alfa bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot golf hotel india juliet kilo lim
a mike november oscar papa quebec romeo sierra tango uniform_victor_wh
iskey_xray yankee zulu
```